# Add image to Notification panel in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, 21.10

Is there a way to add custom image as a background for the notification panel?

[image: This where]

I am currently using Ubuntu21.10 Gnome 40.5

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Not even with messing around with some .css files in themes?

Comment: This is open source, so it certainly can be done modifying source code.

Comment: Ideally I would like to change the "complete panel" But being able to change just the left part would be a good start

Comment: If the calendar part were transparent too it would be great. But as it is too, it looks amazing. Thanks for your time on this....
I think it would be tricky to get the calendar transparent, if so, It would look better if only the left side had the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a workaround.

Download the zip file from github. https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/date-menu-background.

Once you download and extract the original zip as it is(zip file). from the same directory run the below command to install the extension.

```
gnome-extensions install dateMenuBackground.zip
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Restart the gnome-shell with Alt+F2 r method if you are on X11. If you are on wayland, logout and logback in.

Enable the extension with below command

```
gnome-extensions enable dateMenuBackGround@mail.domain.com
```

to use your own background, edit the extensions style sheet file and change the path according to your image path.

```
gedit .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dateMenuBackGround@mail.domain.com/stylesheet.css
```

Content:

```
.my-background {
background-image: url("/usr/share/backgrounds/Impish-Indri_WP_4096x2304_Grey.png");
background-size: cover;
margin-top: 20px; }
```

[image]

Comment: Yes you are correct, sorry my bad, its working for me as well. I was making changes in the downloaded file, not in installed file.

Comment: Thanks man, but i think I can take it from here and make further modifications, it also gives me a chance to explore.